# Can the moderators delete comments on an answer?

Tags: support, comments

The question "[Can a character elect to be considered "running" or "sprinting" even if they don't exceed their walk rate?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/78206/can-a-character-elect-to-be-considered-running-or-sprinting-even-if-they-don/78350)" has an accepted answer.

Another user disagrees with my answer, and started a long conversation in comments, instead of supplying his own contradictory answer. I have deleted my comments, because the comment-conversation was going nowhere.

Can/Will somebody delete the other comments?

Answer (score 11):

Please make sure to flag the offending comments.

Flags are the primary way to notify moderators of anything that needs our attention directly (and only the user who made them or a moderator can delete a comment).

Secondly, if you feel that a comment thread is resolved, please feel free to clear your own comments.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Use the little flag icon beside one or more comments to pop up this menu:

[image]

Just choose the most applicable flag reason, or use the “other…” option to write a custom flag reason. (A custom flag is sometimes useful to indicate that a set of comments need attention without the labour of flagging each one.) These flags go directly to the mods, who will handle them by either completing the request or (if the flag is deemed invalid) dismissing the flag without action.

Comment: Done. It wasn't a whole lot of effort, so I flagged them all individually.